# Spring Security RememberMe & RESTful API

Tags: spring, rest, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to implement an API along the lines of [this guide](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps)

The basic flow is:

- mobile app embeds web view for user to login (normal web app security)
- on login, webapp returns a secure cookie with a token
- mobile app uses the token in all future API requests

So I am trying to secure my webapp to allow normal login flow (with Spring Security) via login form, and then all requests to /api/** are authenticated based on a token passed in request header.

I had originally started implementing this by having two web configs - one for the normal webapp security:

```
@Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/sign-in").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/success").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/loginprocess")
                .failureUrl("/sign-in?loginFailure=true")
                .permitAll();
    }
```

Above just defines standard spring security authentication (custom userDetailsService to get userdetails from DB) and authenticating he login and success pages.

Then another (two files just for clarity/ease of reading) for the API authentication:

```
@Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .antMatcher("/api/**")
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class )
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());
}
```

The above has a pre-auth filter that grabs the relevant HTTP headers from the request (token etc) and adds them to the security context - the custom authentication provider then validates the token/user details.

All good - however, it feels like I am re-inventing a bunch of stuff.  Having looked at Spring Security's RememberMe functionality, it looks like they already handle a lot of this - on login it returns a cookie with a token that can be then used for auto login on future requests. From [the java docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html):

```
<bean id="rememberMeFilter" class=
 "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter">
  <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices"/>
  <property name="authenticationManager" ref="theAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="rememberMeServices" class=
 "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
  <property name="userDetailsService" ref="myUserDetailsService"/>
  <property name="key" value="springRocks"/>
</bean>

<bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class=
 "org.springframework.security.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
  <property name="key" value="springRocks"/>
</bean>
```

The only problem is that I want to include the token in future requests as header params, not a cookie.  I have looked at the source for the above classes and the TokenBasedRememberMeServices class `autoLogin()` method explicitly examines the cookie. The code also uses MD5 as default for hashing.

My questions are:

1. Is there a standard Spring class that can handle RememberMe
   functionality from request headers rather than cookies
2. Is there anything that uses a better hashing algorithm than MD5? (can it be
   easily switched without overriding?). Or, even better - I have come
   across the [KeyBasedPersistenceTokenService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/token/KeyBasedPersistenceTokenService.html) which looks like a
   much better token generation service (SHA512 & additional key info),
   are there any good examples of using that to create/validate the
   secure token.

I would prefer not to have to extend all those classes, as a bunch of the core stuff would be the same, and seems overkill to have to extend them just to change the source of the token and the hashing algorithm.

Comment: any idea with httpBasic() approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, having looked around a little, there didnt seem to be core classes that implemented the RememberMe functionality for request headers - however, reading through the Spring Security remember me source code, it was actually quite simple to extend the above classes to look at the request header.

Details are all here: http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/securing-your-mobile-api-spring-security.html but basically just use RememberMe as normal, but then extend the TokenBasedRememberMeServices and override the extractCookie method to just grab the token from a header rather than a cookie (possibly a little bit hacky, extending a method called extractCookie to grab request headers, but it works)

Comment: Very helpful I was thinking of adopting the same approach.  Did you ever have any luck leveraging something similar to KeyBasedPersistenceTokenService for token generation?

Comment: No I didn't look at using that - I just stuck with the standard RememberMe token generation (as it is deemed good enough for remember-me functionality in the browser I decided not to invest in changing it.